# Powershell for adding permissions to folders without inheritance

Tags: powershell, inheritance, directory, permissions

We have a giant folder located at "D:\Economy" with hundreds of subfolders. We have a new employee which needs permissions for ALL those folders. Unfortunately there are alot of folders without inheritance, so when I add permissions on D:\Economy\ it doesnt apply to all folders.

Ive found many scrips which lists all the folders, but I can't figure out how to also apply permissions to them.
For instance, this command works for finding folders:

```
DIR "D:\Economy" -directory -recurse | GET-ACL | where {$_.Access.IsInherited -eq $false}
```

This command works for setting permissions, but it only applies to those with inheritance enabled:

```
path = "D:\Economy\" 

$acl = Get-Acl $path

$AccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("MYCOMPANY\firstname.surname","Modify","Allow")

$acl.SetAccessRule($AccessRule)

$acl | Set-Acl $path
```

So how do I merge those together?
This is something I wrote up but it doesnt work:

```
$AccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("MYCOMPANY\firstname.surname","Modify","Allow")

$acl.SetAccessRule($AccessRule)

dir "D:\Economy\" -Directory -recurse | get-acl | Where {$_.AreAccessRulesProtected} | set-acl "D:\Economy\"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$AccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("MYCOMPANY\firstname.surname","Modify","Allow")

Get-ChildItem "D:\Economy\" -Directory -Recurse | %{
    $acl = Get-Acl -Path $_.FullName
    if ($acl.AreAccessRulesProtected) {
        $acl.AddAccessRule($AccessRule)
        $acl | Set-Acl -Path $_.FullName
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for your help! I tried running it but no rights are applied. But no error codes either. Yes I have replaced "MYCOMPANY\firstname.surname" :D Any ideas?

Comment: this will add an ACE only if the directory doesn't inherit the parent. Else the ACL on the directory is untouched. Check on a directory where inheritance is disabled.